# How to keep label from going off the screen in kivy when we type big text?

Tags: python, kivy, chatbot

I'm trying to create a chatbot. As soon as I click the button it creates a new widget but if the input is too long it goes off screen. I'm not able to figure out how to keep all the code in the screen.

Python code

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

import time


class MyFL(FloatLayout):

    input = ObjectProperty(None)


    def btn(self):

        self.add_widget(Label( text= '>$' + self.input.text, pos=(-650, 100)))

        
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyFL()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Kv code

```
    <FloatLayout>:
    
        input:input
    
        TextInput:
            id: input
            multiline: False
            hint_text: "Say Something"
            size_hint: 1, 0.05
            font_size: 20
    
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.05, 0.05
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.06 }
            on_press: root.btn()
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `Label` doesn't do line wrapping, I suggest using a readonly `TextInput`. In your python you can define a custom `TextInput`:

```
class MyTextInput(TextInput):
    pass
```

and use it in your `btn()` method:

```
def btn(self):
    self.add_widget(MyTextInput(text='>$' + self.input.text, pos_hint={'y':0.15}))
```

Plus a rule in your 'kv` for the new class:

```
<MyTextInput>:
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: self.minimum_height
    readonly: True
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it works perfectly in all case (but I tested, might be ok)

I do in this way:

In `main.py`

```
import kivy
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.clock import Clock

# I use this to load kivy string
# easier for me to manipulate : )
kivy.lang.Builder.load_string("""
#:kivy 2.0.0
    
<MyFL>:
    input: input
        
    TextInput:
        id: input
        multiline: False
        hint_text: "Say Something"
        size: root.width, root.height *0.05
        font_size: 20
        focus: True
        
        on_text_validate:  # this allow you to add widget when hit enter in the textinput
            root.btn()  # by calling the func btn()

    # Button:
    #     size_hint: 0.05, 0.05
    #     pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.06 }
    #     on_release:
    #         root.btn()
""")


class MyFL(Widget):  # I changed the class to inherit widget instead of floatlayout, just the positioning is different, you can change this 

    def btn(self):
        label = Label(text = '>$ ' + self.input.text, center = self.center)
        label.multiline = True
        label.font_size = 25

        self.add_widget(label)


    def update(self, dt):  # newly added #
        # pass
        for i in self.children:  # loop through all children

            if i != self.ids.input and i.texture_size[0] > self.width:  # if children is label
                # see how many line it should split
                lines = round(i.texture_size[0] / self.width) + 1

                for split in range(lines):  # split the text
                    text = i.text.split(" ")
                    index = int(len(text)*split / lines)
                    text.insert(index, "\n")
                    text = " ".join(text)
                    i.text = text


class MyApp(App):
    main = MyFL()

    def build(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.main.update, 0.1)  # schedule the clock to make update

        return self.main


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Explanations are in the code above, this is not the perfect answer but I hope it helps.